# Using yarn workspace from monorepo as git module

Tags: git, github, yarnpkg, monorepo, yarn-workspaces

Let's say I have a repo configured like

```
repoX
|_ pkgA
|_ pkgB
|_ pkgC
```

is it possible to use `pkgC` from `repoX` as a git submodule in `repoY`?

```
repoY
|_ pkgX
|_ pkgC (-> repoX)
```

Constraints:

- `repoX` and `repoY` are private
- `pkgABC` are yarn workspaces
- `repoX` should not be accessible completely for users in `repoY` only `pkgC`

Answer (score 0):

I think generally there are 3 ways of dealing with this:

**#1 git submodules solution**: git submodules require that you have a top-level `pkgC` repository. You can generate it regularly using [git-filter-repo](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo), which is recommended over `git filter-branch`. The idea:

1. Clone repoX
2. Rewrite the clone to only include history from pkgC/
3. Use new repo as a subrepo.
4. Repeat.
   For example:

```sh
set -x
set -e

git clone repoX repoX-to-rewrite
git -C repoX-to-rewrite filter-repo--subdirectory-filter pkgC/
git -C repoY submodule add repoX-to-rewrite pkgC
```

This solution has various *drawbacks* and I strongly discourage it. It requires that you rewrite the history. Most importantly it involves a destructive operation `filter-repo/filter-branch` and can go wrong.

**#2 git subtree**: You can use `git subtree` to solve the issue. The advantage is that it completely pulls the history, it's easy to use and personally I prefer it over submodules. The idea is as follows:

1. Split a pkgC into a subtree in the current repoX and create a fetchable branch.
2. Merge branch into repoY using git subtree pull.
3. Repeat.

```sh
set -x
set -e
# split a subtree. this is a save operation
git -C repoX subtree split -b upstream-pkgc pkgC
# add to repoY
git -C repoY subtree add --prefix pkgC ../repoX upstream-pkgc

## to update
# split a subtree and then merge it into repoY. this should be a fast-forward since
# subtree splits are stable.
git -C repoX subtree split -b upstream-pkgc pkgC
git -C repoY subtree pull --prefix pkgC ../repoX upstream-pkgc
```

This is a good solution. There might be some additional details your script must take care of and some options to choose from (e.g. do you want to use `--squash`), but generally it works fine.

**#3 pkg management**: Depending on the pkg manager you use, you can publish pkgC to an internal managed package registry and then use something like yarn to pull it from there. If you have that option, it's probably the most natural and doesn't require git incantations.